# How to parse a string to make objects suitable for inserting into ARGV?

Tags: ruby

I'm using `optparse` to parse the command line in a Ruby program.

I'd like to add the ability for the user to have an environment variable `MYAPP_OPTIONS` with a string containing options that would normally be specified on the command line, e.g. `--verbose`. I'd like to prepend `ARGV` with these options.

Is there already some kind of built in way to do this? I know how I could manipulate the `ARGV` array directly, but how would I parse the string into the list of ARG's? It's not as simple as splitting on spaces because the space might be quoted and part of an argument.

Comment: Hint: You can call `parse` on anything you want.

Comment: @tadman Yes, but I would still need to parse the string into args, right? The docs say "parse(*argv, into: nil)
Parses command line arguments argv in order when environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, and in permutation mode otherwise."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shellwords is the Ruby library that handles this kind of thing, and it can be accomplished by something like this:

```
[6] pry(main)> require 'shellwords'
false
[7] pry(main)> Shellwords.shellsplit %Q{ arg1 "arg2a arg2b"}
[
    [0] "arg1",
    [1] "arg2a arg2b"
]
```

Prepending these to an array can be done like this:

```
[13] pry(main)> my_argv = %w(foo bar) # create a sample array to illustrate
[
    [0] "foo",
    [1] "bar"
]

[18] pry(main)> my_argv.unshift(Shellwords.shellsplit %Q{ arg1 "arg2a arg2b"}).flatten!
[
    [0] "arg1",
    [1] "arg2a arg2b",
    [2] "foo",
    [3] "bar"
]
```